# Props not showing error when there is typo in identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

This is my `App.js` file

```
import Data from "./second"
    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Data
           given_data = 'This is data'></Data>
        </div>
     );
    }

export default App;
```

This is my `second.js` file

```
function Data(props)
{
    return(

        <div >
           <p>{props.given_data}</p>
        </div>

    );
}

export default Data;
```

If I mistype `props.given_data` of `second.js` as `props.given_dattttaa` or something else it does not show any error, why?

Without any any error I can't find what I have done wrong?

Is there any way to show error either in browser console or editor terminal?

Comment: Do you want to forcefully display error screen if specific prop is not passed?

Comment: that's just Javascript for you, it's a very weakly-typed language. If this bothers you you can use Typescript or, if that's too much effort and runtime errors are enough, use [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are using plain Javascript, thus there is no way to determine what is actually passed as `props` until the code is actually called.

This is what [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) was (more or less) invented for. Loosely speaking, Typescript allows you to use Javascript but with types, or in other words: Typescript is Javascript with "some extra documentation". A quick start guide is provided [in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html).

For your specific case, you could then type the `props` object as follows.

```js
// define whatever you are going to pass to props
type DataProps = {
    given_data: string
}

function Data(props: DataProps){
   console.log(props.given_data)
   ....
}
```

After you have done the setup, you will notice that typescript will complain if you access something different in `props` than `given_data`.